# auto detect added class in highlight.js for dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor, highlight.js

i am using highlight.js 9 and added it like the following

```
 <script src="highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>
```

i am using ckeditor which adds highlight.js class on the fly.I need to append content in a div.When i append it i want highlight.js will detect which language class is used by editor and   apply styles automatically when i append it to my page .How to achieve this?

say i am have the following content in my editor:

```
<pre>
<code class="language-css"><pre> <code>hljs.configure({useBR: true}); $('div.code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});</code></pre></code>
```

which results in the following styling:

[image]

when i will append it my page i want the exact same styling as i am seeing on the editor .How to do that.

a image of ***div id='content'*** currently it shows no styling :

[image]

Comment: what does it display when you append it on the page right now?

Comment: only the text content with no styling...check the new image i added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. I had to use the following code inside onclick event handler:

```
 $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
});
```

full code:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1');
var content = $("#content");
function lol(event) {

    var el = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
    alert(el);
    var html = $.parseHTML(el);

    content.append(html);

    $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
}
```